# Android : ANR in Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

Getting ANR in the application while using GA.

Using

**compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'**

Trace below :

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41d0ed08 self=0x419530e8
| sysTid=15869 nice=-11 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074995540
| state=S schedstat=( 321620545 42516968278 6171 ) utm=18 stm=13 core=0

at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x41d0edd8> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=1 (main)

at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:400)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:162)
at com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzb.zzhI((null):-1)
at com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics.zzhk((null):-1)
at com.google.android.gms.analytics.ExceptionReporter.uncaughtException((null):-1)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please suggest if you have faced similar issue in past

Comment: Did you searched on maven whether this package even exists? or you have added the jar and added as dependencies? I have used google analytics before but it didn't required any library dependency.

Comment: This is what google docs says at https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Yes, it's there in the document.
But interestingly when I searched for it on search.maven.org ; I couldn't find any result.
Anyways, I followed the link below when I used Google Analaytics; see if you can acheive using this.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/
And do update the answer if you come to any solution using your link.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing except instead of showing `((null):-1)` at the end of each line it shows `(unavailable:-1)`, don't know if theres a different answer or not but I also cannot find anything regarding either of these cases so if anyone has info on that maybe it can also help.

Answer (score 2):

I wasted a day on searching the solution (I have the same thread dump) and released that it's not directly related to Google Analytics. The root cause was the next line: adView.destroy(); where adView == null. Seems Google Analytics tried to send this exception and crashed itself.
I found it by disabling Google Analytics at all.

Comment: In my case the ANR was causing the exception to not be reported to analytics, somehow one got through though and it appears to be that the exception is causing google analytics to put the app in ANR. However I fixed the exception and while it fixed the ANR on the devices I was using, one of the users is still having the problem.